# Issue: Reading 10 different marks into my marks variable. FOR loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.*;

public class loops

{

public static void main (String []args)

    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in).useDelimiter("\n");

        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
        {
                    System.out.print("Enter your mark:  ");
                    int marks = input.nextInt(); 
        }

        int marks = + input.nextInt();
        int totalmarks = marks / 10;

        System.out.println("The class average was:"+ totalmarks + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: mayank jain helped me by adding an additional variable (sum=0) and accumulating the inputs into it. Many thanks I will endeavour to learn this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clearly asked but according to my interpretation, the problem is to add all the input marks and give the average, so declare a sum variable with initial value 0 and add all the marks coming as input and take the average.

```
import java.util.*;

public class loops

{

public static void main (String []args)

{

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
    int sum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
                System.out.print("Enter your mark:  ");
                int marks = input.nextInt(); 
                sum=sum+marks;
    }


    int totalmarks = sum / 10;

    System.out.println("The class average was:"+ totalmarks + ".");
}
}
```

Comment: I hope this is what you wanted @joeblog